# Можно ли привести (скастить) двумерный массив к T**?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели

Я пробовал данный способ:

```
double arr[5][5];
double **ptr = (double **)arr;
```

Все это дело компилируется, но обращение `ptr[][]` к массиву используя указатель приводит к: **SEGFAULT**

Собственно, вопрос, можно ли осуществить взаимодейстие с двумерным массивом через ptr**?

Comment: В С в принципе отсутствует возможность присваивать массивы. Выражение `(double **)arr` следует читать как "представь, что в это указатель на указатель на double". Что касается левой части, то `double **ptr = ` является присвоением к `ptr`, а не к `**ptr`. Звездочки в этом контексте - это часть объявления типа.

Comment: @megorit, а что такое скастить?

Comment: @PavelGridin, от слова *cast*: `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `const_cast`. То же что и привести тип. Наверно это применимо по-большей части к C++ (сленг?). Дословно - *бросить*.

Answer (score 2):

Ну... можно так:

```
double arr[5][5];
double *ptr = (double *)arr;
```

А обращение `arr[i][j]` при этом будет выглядеть как

```
*(ptr + 5*i+j)
```

https://ideone.com/VIKiTT

Comment: Где-то я видел подобную конструкцию...

Comment: Все-таки, это вызывает SEGFAULT.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не данный пример, а использование double** ptr.

Comment: А зачем вы его используете? Надеетесь на `ptr[i][j]`? Вы не понимаете, что размещение в памяти для этого должно быть совершенно иным? Что двумерный массив и массив указателей совершенно разные вещи?

Answer (score 1):

##### В чём ошибка?

```cpp
double arr[5][5];
double** ptr = (double**)arr;
```

Вот здесь вы скастили `double(*)[5]` к `double**`. Дальше, при первом разыменовании `arr[row]` вы получаете *мусорный адрес*, а при втором `arr[row][col]` - *segfault*.

Конструкция `array[idx]` является *синтаксическим сахаром* для `*(array+idx)`. Таким образом, `array[row][col]` - это `*(*(array+row)+col)`.

##### Массивы и указатели

Массив может быть приведён только к указателю на первый элемент (*array to pointer decay*). Двумерные массивы тут исключением не являются:

```cpp
constexpr int rows = 5;
constexpr int cols = 7;

double array[rows][cols];

double (*ptr1)[cols] = array; // double(*)[7] - указатель на массив double[7]

double* ptr2 = *array; // уазатель на первый элемент первого подмассива
// здесь происходит двойной 'array to pointer decay' через разыменование

for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        ptr2[row*cols+col] = 0; // any expression
```

##### C++23: operator[]

А ещё в `C++23` появился `operator[](Ts...)`, который может принимать аргументы разных типов по принципу: `object["string"s,37,3.14159]`. Так что вы можете создать свой класс для удобства: `array[row,col]`.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145975/discussion-on-answer-by-megorit-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. В статической матрице присутствуют элементы только типа `double`. А в массиве указателей первые элементы только типа указатель `double *`.
И приведение к неправильному типу приводит только к неопределённому поведению.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка сегмента SEGFAULT, в твоём случае происходит от того что С чито физический не может понять от какого места начинать следующий сегмент.

Фактический он знает где находится элемент [0][0], а вот где находится [1][0] после того как ты привел значение в указатель?

double* - это уже не массив, это некий адрес в памяти, в котором **возможно** что-то хранится (а возможно и нет), и каков размер сегмента памяти, и каков обьем памяти может предсказать только ванга или программист ручками.

Сделай указатель на [0][0] просто сказав что double* а второй ряд массива доставай простой математикой - 7й элемент многомерки это будет твой 0й элемент первого [1][0] ряда.

И - да естественно что double* можно привести обратно в double X[5][5] используя обычное статическое преобразование.

Это как раз очень сильная сторона С и Pascal, что все что угодно может стать памятью и память может обратно стать объектом.